# How is the atomic number of a beta particle zero?

Tags: radioactivity

In my textbook, $\ce{β-}$ particle is denoted as $_{-1}e^0$. This means that the atomic number of $\ce{β-}$ is $\ce{-1}$. But that doesn't make any sense. Also, how is the mass number of $\ce{β-}$ zero? I mean it must have some mass right? How can it be massless?

Comment: I will start you off: mass number is not mass. Mass number is total protons plus neutrons, so it is zero for an electron.

Comment: But what is the meaning of having atomic number equal to $-1$? Total number of protons equal to $-1$? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: An electron has a negative charge, hasn't it ?

Comment: Get a better textbook, the authors of this one have no idea what they are writing about, or it's poor editorial job. Either way, beta particle is denoted with e, e⁻ or β⁻. All particle symbols are upright and the charge is denoted in a superscript.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense in a pedantic or slightly silly way. A proton can be defined as having atomic number (Z) of +1. After all, it is the nucleus of the simplest hydrogen isotope and atomic number is number of protons in an atom. So a neutron has Z = 0 because it has no protons. But, in free space, neutrons spontaneously decay, in roughly 15 minutes, to protons, electrons and electron antineutrinos. So, ignoring the neutrino, assigning the electron as Z = -1 keeps the bookkeeping honest, i.e., 0 goes to +1 plus -1.

Comment: Also, it is best not to dwell on such contrived stuff: people who write beginning level chemistry books often strive for an artificial consistency, leading to what you have encountered. I have seen it as well and been annoyed by it. So what @andselisk says is good advice: get a better book, if you have the opportunity.

Comment: @EdV you forgot the antineutrino. β⁻ decay is not *only* emission of an electron.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I did not forget: read my comment again.